# usage of 'having been + past participle'

Tags: perfect-constructions, participle-clauses, reduced-relative-clauses, supplementation

Is it okay to use 'Having been+third form' as the reduction of Passive Relative Clause in Simple Past Tense in order to put more emphasis?

> The actor who was chosen for the role is looking for a suitable costume now
>
> The actor chosen for the role is looking for a suitable costume now

Is this reduction correct?

> The actor having been chosen for the role is looking for a suitable costume now

(more emphasis on the action of 'being chosen' ?)

and what about these sentences? are they correct?

> The singers who have been selected for the contest are going to rehearse today.
>
> The singers having been selected for the contest are going to rehearse today.
>
> Only the contestants who had been considered adequate got the right to compete in the finals.
>
> Only the contestants having been considered adequate got the right to compete in the finals

Can you make a full explanation about where to use 'having been+third form' ? can we say 'whenever we use present perfect or past perfect' ?

Answer (score 4):

> Is it okay to use 'Having been+third form' as the reduction of Passive Relative Clause in Simple Past Tense in order to put more emphasis?

In a word, no—because *BE having been VERB<sup>PaPpl</sup>* is not a valid English construction.

(*In what follows, * marks the following utterance as ungrammatical*.)

There is a very strict rule governing the sequence of auxiliary verbs, one piece of which is that auxiliary *HAVE* **cannot** be cast in the progressive construction. We cannot, for instance, say

> *The actor **is having** been chosen for the role *or*
>   *The contestants **were having** been considered adequate.

(**Lexical** *HAVE* **can** be cast in the progressive—<sup>ok</sup>*I **am having** a good time*—but auxiliary *HAVE* cannot.)

The sort of reduction you're talking about is called 'Whiz reduction': it involves deleting a *wh=* relativizer **and** a following form of *BE*:

> The actor <s>**who was**</s> chosen
>   The contestants <s>**who were**</s> considered adequate.

Consequently, your proposed sentences represent 'Whiz-reduction' of  illegitimate unreduced forms:

> *The actor **<s>who was</s> having** been selected
>   *The contestants **<s>who were</s> having** been considered adequate.

You can, however, use *having been VERB<sup>PaPpl</sup>* in contexts where preceding *BE* is not implied—typically as a supplemental participle clause:

> Having been selected for the role, the actor is now looking for a suitable costume.

In this case *having* is not a component of a progressive construction but an ordinary present participle. The clause *having been selected...* is not an adjunct ('modifier')—it doesn't just tell you which actor is being talked about. It is a supplement: it makes a separate assertion about the actor. It represents an underlying *The actor **has** been selected*, with *has* cast as a present participle so the clause can be 'attached' to the main clause as a subordinate. The perfect construction indicates that this event, the actor's selection, took place before the action of the main clause.

And this sort of subordinate participle clause can also be moved into the position where you have put it in your rewrites; but it **must** be 'bracketed off' from the main clause with commas, to mark it as a supplement, not an adjunct:

> The actor**`,`** having been chosen for the role**`,`** is looking for a suitable costume now